# How to solve SQL Column not found error in magento2

Tags: magento2

[image]

My **magento2** **home page** is not display it gives above errors

Any one have idea?

Comment: I think your inchoo featured product module's table is not generated so please check that first

Comment: Can you share the link of featured product code you are using from inchoo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Disable third party extension after flash ....
May be issue generate in inchoo extension so disable after checking...
Happy coding...